# jquery onclick or keyup open new window to collect data

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on **addressbook** in **php**. I have a textarea, I want that when I click or keyup on that textarea, a new window should open with another form with fields like address, city, state, pin, country and a submit button.

When I click on submit button, I must back to the previous page. and the combination of address, city,... should be in textarea

As I already doing is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('textarea').on('keyup click',function(){
    window.open("Open-New-window-while-Inserting-Address2.php");
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity.... Why do you need that back&forth pages thing? And with some textarea that does actually nothing?

Comment: As we add new address in **Outlook**

Comment: If you're not using a `textarea` as a `textarea` (a place to type things), then don't make it a `textarea`.  Popping up a window *on every keystroke* for a text input seems like a horrible idea.  Give the users a button to click to invoke this pop-up functionality, and display the values on the page when the pop-up is dismissed.  As for the pop-up itself, this will be *a lot* easier if it's a modal `<div>` on the same page instead of a completely different page.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it this way, use a Modal instead of opening a new window. When the user "keysup" on from the Textarea, a modal would popup with whatever form you want it to display and when the user is done, you save the data with JS and load it into your TextArea.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://bootsnipp.com/tags/modal) and choose whatever Modal template you want, then modify it to suit your needs. And When a user clicks the Save button, you can access the values from the textfields using jQuery. example: `$('#textArea').val($('#name').val() ...)` and so on

Answer (score -1):

In your page that contain your text area add the form information as a variables then if they are isset and not null write them with in your text area else print empty one.

Comment: May I know why I voted down for this answer it is a perfect answer first the question don't say a pop up window second, I answered it about the question itself it didnot include asking about best way to do that or about opinion about the task